# UI-router. Dynamically replace root state's template

Tags: angularjs, templates, angular-ui-router

I have a root state `app` which defines master template. I have a need of switching this template with a different one for a certain route:

```
app.run(($rootScope, $state) => {
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', (toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) => {
    const rootState = $state.get('app');

    if (toState.name === 'app.new') {
      rootState.template = require('../../new_layout.tpl.html');
    } else {
      rootState.template = require('../../layout.tpl.html');
    }
  }
}
```

This method works for initial app load, as well as for first in app state change (but only when changing to `new_layout`). When I'm trying to switch from `app.new` to some other state, `rootState's.template` changes but is not being applied(rendered).

Is there a legit way to dynamically replace root state's template property?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using ui-router View Targeting.

```
  $stateProvider.state({ 
    name: 'app', 
    url: '/app', 
    templateUrl: 'layout1.html',
  });

  $stateProvider.state({ 
    name: 'app.new', 
    url: '/new', 
    views: {
      // Target the unnamed ("") ui-view created in the root ("")
      "@": { templateUrl: 'layout2.html' },
      // Target the unnamed ("") ui-view in the layout2 created by this state
      "@app.new": { template: '<h1>app.new content</h1>' }
    }
  });
```

Working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/PmPn7kp1u1bRGeYeXK2H?p=preview

when `app.new` (or any substate) is active, it overrides the contents of the root ui-view using `layout2.html`.  Then it puts its own content inside the layout2.html's `ui-view`.